# Solr Dashboard JVM-Memory chart, what do the two marks mean?

Tags: solr

The Solr admin console has a chart on it called "JVM-Memory", which might look for example like this:

[image]

I think this means my JVM max size (-Xmx) is 2GB. And it's currently using 98.4MB of JVM RAM (4.8% of 2GB).

So, what is that other line at 854MB, the light grey bar? What does that mean?

I have not successfully found any documentation of this Solr admin dashboard UI by googling. The chart doesn't have any mouseovers or on-screen explanations.

Anyone know?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (no ref.) but I think you are right about the used/max values, and that the third one relates to the [commited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html) memory, that is the total amount of memory guaranteed to be available for use by the JVM. Also if we inspect the DOM we can see that this value is represented by elements with class `bar-total`, the other 2 being referenced by class `bar-used` and `bar-max`.

Comment: i think you are right!